Why nginx tries to set up proxy cache when started by root?
My nginx.conf file have no proxy statement. If I start it on a sandbox filesystem as user http with starts up fine. If I try to start with as root, it fails with chown("/var/lib/nginx/proxy", 33) failed (30: Read-only file system)
The filesystem is readonly on both cases. Why only fail when starting as root? The dir is also owned by host (non-sandboxed) root, so it would have tried to chown on both cases.
ideally I want nginx to only serve static content, never redirect anything anywhere.
Tried to add, in the only location / {}, in the only server {} object, in the only http {} object:
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_cache off;

But still get the error.
